# Rspec and SQL: Index 0 is out of range

Tags: sql, ruby, database, rspec

I am trying to run my code and I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Bookmark.new(id: res[0]['id'], title: res[0]['title'], url: res[0]['url'])
 IndexError: Index 0 is out of range
```

I checked my database table and saw it is all good, there is data there (bookmarks) so not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: What is returned by `res`?

Comment: Hi spickermann, it's meant to be all the bookmarks I have in my database in bookmark_manager_test

Comment: Please add some code here.  We cannot help without seeing what causes the issue.  Read [ask] and [mcve].  To debug, dump the content of `res`, something is wrong with your indexing obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, it was an error on my part. My spec_helper file was referring to a different ENVIRONMENT compared to my code. That's why it couldn't find the data it needed. It's at least a good learning curve for next time